# Create shell script from Extendscript Toolkit

Tags: bash, shell, extendscript

As one of the outputs from an Extendscript, I want to create a shell script which can then be executed by the user. Here is a very basic example:

```
function createShellScript()
{
    var contents = "#!/bin/bash\ndate";
    var outputFolder = Folder.selectDialog ("Choose where to save:");
    var shFile = new File(outputFolder.absoluteURI + "/shell.sh");
    shFile.open("W");
    shFile.write(contents);
    shFile.close();
}
createShellScript ();
```

If I take the resulting file (`shell.sh`), run `chmod +x` on it to make it exectuable, and then run it, nothing happens.
If, however, I adjust the script above to create the same content but a text file – so it outputs `shell.txt`  open the file, copy the contents into a blank document in a code editor, and save as a `.sh` file, and then `chmod` and run it, it works fine.

Why does Extendscript not produce a proper `.sh` file when using this method?

Thanks for any help.

S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the line feed characters to unix style. For example, `shFile.lineFeed = "Unix";`.

```
function createShellScript()
{
    var contents = "#!/bin/bash\ndate";
    var outputFolder = Folder.selectDialog ("Choose where to save:");
    var shFile = new File(outputFolder.absoluteURI + "/shell.sh");
    shFile.open("W");
    shFile.lineFeed = "Unix";
    shFile.write(contents);
    shFile.close();
}
createShellScript ();
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thank you!